# Update PartialView works only once

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I call a javascript to update a record, and then display the result.
This works, but only once.
The second time, it seems that my button doesn't fire anymore.

```
        $("button[name='verlengknop']").click(function () {
            var spid=$(this).attr("id");
            console.log("button pressed");
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Verlengen", "Uitleen")",
                type: "post",
                data: { spid:spid },
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#partial").html(result);
                }
            });
        })
```

The first time, the console.log shows 'button pressed', the record is updated and the PartialView shows the new values, so I guess that part isn't the reason why this does not work twice.
The second time, I don't see 'button pressed' in the console.log anymore.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Verlengen(int spid)
    {
        var entity = _context.TblUitleen.FirstOrDefault(item => item.UitleenId == spid);
        var lener = entity.lenerid;
        if (entity != null)
        {
          entity.verlengingen = 10;
          _context.TblUitleen.Update(entity);
          _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        var uit = _context.TblUitleen.Where(uit => uit.lenerid == lener
                                                   && uit.teruggebracht == false).ToList();
        var viewModel = new GezinUitleen()
        {
            Uitleningen = uit

        };
        return PartialView("LeenDetailView",viewModel);
    }
```

Partial View:

```
<h4>Uitleningen :</h4>
<table class='table-sm table-striped'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        @*<th>Uitleen ID</th>*@
        <th>Omschrijving</th>
        <th>Datum uit</th>
        <th>Datum in</th>
        <th>Verlengingen</th>
        <th></th>
        <!--kolom verl.knop -->
        <th></th>
        <!--kolom terugknop -->

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Uitleningen)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.UitleenId</td>
            <td>@item.speelgoedomschrijving</td>
            <td>@Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.datumuit))</td>
            <td>@Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.datumin))</td>
            <td>@item.verlengingen</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-info" name="verlengknop" id=@item.UitleenId>Verlengen</button> 
 </td>
            <td><button class=" btn btn-success">Teruggebracht</button></td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

What am I doing wrong here?
thanks,
James

Comment: Hi can you replace  $("button[name='verlengknop']").click(function () { with

Comment: $(document).on('click', 'button[name='verlengknop']', function (e) {

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your below code. in your partial view so this issue will be resolved. and please add also click event in document.ready

```
<h4>Uitleningen :</h4>
<table class='table-sm table-striped'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        @*<th>Uitleen ID</th>*@
        <th>Omschrijving</th>
        <th>Datum uit</th>
        <th>Datum in</th>
        <th>Verlengingen</th>
        <th></th>
        <!--kolom verl.knop -->
        <th></th>
        <!--kolom terugknop -->

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Uitleningen)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.UitleenId</td>
            <td>@item.speelgoedomschrijving</td>
            <td>@Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.datumuit))</td>
            <td>@Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.datumin))</td>
            <td>@item.verlengingen</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-info" name="verlengknop" id=@item.UitleenId>Verlengen</button> 
 </td>
            <td><button class=" btn btn-success">Teruggebracht</button></td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $("button[name='verlengknop']").click(function () {
           var spid=$(this).attr("id");
           console.log("button pressed");
           $.ajax({
               url: "@Url.Action("Verlengen", "Uitleen")",
               type: "post",
               data: { spid:spid },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#partial").html(result);
                    }
                });
            })
</script>
```

Or you can also create a function like below:

```
<h4>Uitleningen :</h4>
    <table class='table-sm table-striped'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @*<th>Uitleen ID</th>*@
            <th>Omschrijving</th>
            <th>Datum uit</th>
            <th>Datum in</th>
            <th>Verlengingen</th>
            <th></th>
            <!--kolom verl.knop -->
            <th></th>
            <!--kolom terugknop -->

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Uitleningen)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.UitleenId</td>
                <td>@item.speelgoedomschrijving</td>
                <td>@Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.datumuit))</td>
                <td>@Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.datumin))</td>
                <td>@item.verlengingen</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-info" onclick="myclick(this)" name="verlengknop" id=@item.UitleenId>Verlengen</button> 
     </td>
                <td><button class=" btn btn-success">Teruggebracht</button></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    </table>


function myclick(obj){
  var spid=$(obj).attr("id");
               console.log("button pressed");
               $.ajax({
                   url: "@Url.Action("Verlengen", "Uitleen")",
                   type: "post",
                   data: { spid:spid },
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#partial").html(result);
                        }
                    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[name='verlengknop']', function (e) {
```

by yash vadhvani is the correct answer.